# FILE pf lost its value

Tags: c, file, runtime-error, fclose

Program and file created as I wished. But when program about to end `(void main() {...return 0;})` I get an error. When I check for `pFile` value on main function its like it never exist.

Please Help.
Thank a head! :)

```
FILE *pFile;
char name[SIZE];
int amount;
float finalPrice;


pFile = fopen("shoppingList.txt","r+");
if(pFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    return;
}
CacuShoppingList(pFile);
}





void CacuShoppingList(FILE *pFile)
{
FILE *p2File, *p3File;
char name[SIZE];
int amount;
float unitPrice, sum;
long placeHolder;
int flag;

p2File = fopen("shoppingList.txt", "a");
p3File = fopen("prices.txt", "r");
sum = 0;

while(fscanf(pFile,"%s %d", name, &amount) && amount)
{
    placeHolder = ftell(pFile);
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if(IsProductExist(p3File, name))
    {
        fprintf(p2File, "%s quntity=%d unit price=%.2f total price=%.2f\n",name, amount,unitPrice = GetProductPrice(p3File, name, amount), amount*unitPrice);
        sum += amount*unitPrice;
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf(p2File, "%s not found on price list\n ",name);
    }

    fseek(pFile, placeHolder, SEEK_SET);
}

fprintf(p2File,"\nthe overall price for this shopping is %.2f",sum); 
flag = fclose(pFile);
flag = fclose(p2File);
flag = fclose(p3File);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please include the error you get.

Comment: By the way, are modifying the same file you are reading? At the same time? That is really something I recommend *against*.

Comment: I don't see a check to see if `p2File` and `p3File` have opened successfully.